# Beyond Compare, special marker for expected diff lines in a file

Tags: beyondcompare4

How can one create a section of a file thats always expected to be different?

Sample jenkinsfile (basically javascript):

```
//!beyond-comp:ignorediff

//!beyond-comp:ignorediff-end
```

Sample CMD script:

```
REM!beyond-compare:ignorediff
set VAR1=some_specific_value
set VAR2=some_value
REM!beyond-compare:ignorediff-end
```

Sample YAML:

```yaml
#!beyond-comp:ignorediff
environment:
- var1: some_specific_value
- var2: some_value
#!beyond-comp:ignorediff-end
```

primary use case is batch file/jenkinsfile/etc with a section that is 100% expected to be different between repos, ie setting specific values, where its cumbersome to use env variables

I'm assuming theres a Grammar thing to do this, but I looked through it and couldn't make heads or tails of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mark text unimportant in Beyond Compare 4's Text Compare for *.cmd files:

1. Select **Tools > File Formats**.
2. Click **+**.
3. **Text Format**.
4. **General** tab.
5. **Mask**: `*.cmd`.
6. **Grammar** tab.
7. Click **+** in the top half of the tab.
8. **Element name**: ignorediff.
9. **Category**: Delimited
10. **Text From**: `!beyond-compare:ignorediff`.
11. **to**: `!beyond-compare:ignorediff-end`.
12. Click **OK**.
13. **Save**.
14. Close the **File Formats** dialog.
15. Load a pair of CMD files in the Text Compare.
16. Click the **Rules** toolbar button (referee icon).
17. Uncheck the ignorediff grammar element to make it unimportant.
18. Change the dropdown at the bottom of the dialog from **Use for this view only** to **Also update session defaults**.
19. Click **OK**.
20. Make sure **View > Ignore Unimportant Differences** is turned on.

Reference: [Define Unimportant Text in Beyond Compare](https://www.scootersoftware.com/kb/unimportantv3).